# iOS Request Timeout Posting Images To S3 With A Pre-signed URL/Alamofire

Tags: ios, amazon-s3, alamofire

I'm very close to being able to PUT images to my S3 bucket with a signed URL from an iOS device using Alamofire, but I'm getting a request timeout.

I have a Node backend generating pre-signed URL's with the following code:

```
var aws = require('aws-sdk');
var config = require('../config');
const uuid = require('uuid');

aws.config.update({accessKeyId: config.accessKeyId, secretAccessKey: config.secretAccessKey});

exports.getSignedImageUploadURL = function(filetype, callback) {
  var s3 = new aws.S3();

  var filename = uuid.v4();
  var params = {
    Bucket: 'xxx',
    Key: filename,
    Expires: 4000,
    ContentType: "image/jpeg"
  };
  s3.getSignedUrl('putObject', params, function(err, data) {
    if (err) {
      console.log(err);
      callback(err, null);
    } else {
      callback(null, data);
    }
  });
}
```

And I can PUT images with Postman successfully with the following options:

[image]

[image]

But it seems I'm struggling to replicate these conditions with an Alamofire request. I'm currently using the following code:

```
Alamofire.upload(.PUT, postURL, headers: ["Content-Type": "image/jpeg"], multipartFormData: { multipartFormData in
    if let image = image, imageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image, 1.0) {
        multipartFormData.appendBodyPart(data: imageData, name: "file", mimeType: "image/jpeg")
    }
}, encodingCompletion: { encodingResult in
        switch encodingResult {
        case .Success(let upload, _, _):
            upload.responseJSON { response in
                print("RESPONSE JSON", response)
            }
        case .Failure(let encodingError):
            print("ENCODING ERROR", encodingError)
        }
    }
)
```

To get the following error:

```
RESPONSE JSON FAILURE: Error Domain=NSURLErrorDomain Code=-1001 "The request timed out." 
UserInfo={NSUnderlyingError=0x7fee750cfc90 {Error Domain=kCFErrorDomainCFNetwork Code=-1001 "(null)" UserInfo={_kCFStreamErrorCodeKey=-2102, _kCFStreamErrorDomainKey=4}}, 
NSErrorFailingURLStringKey=https://xxx.s3.amazonaws.com/f01ab7e0-ecdc-4f19-93f0-4f1d89b2903c?AWSAccessKeyId=xxx&Content-Type=image%2Fjpeg&Expires=1468384920&Signature=xxx, 
NSErrorFailingURLKey=https://xxx.s3.amazonaws.com/f01ab7e0-ecdc-4f19-93f0-4f1d89b2903c?AWSAccessKeyId=xxx&Content-Type=image%2Fjpeg&Expires=1468384920&Signature=xxx, 
_kCFStreamErrorDomainKey=4, _kCFStreamErrorCodeKey=-2102, NSLocalizedDescription=The request timed out.}
```

Any ideas?

EDIT:

I've also tried this code to the same error:

```
if let image = image, imageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image, 1.0) {
    Alamofire.upload(.PUT, postURL, headers: ["Content-Type": "image/jpeg"], data: imageData)
        .response { (req, res, json, error) in
            print(req, res, json, error)
            completionHandler(success: false)
            return
    }
}
```

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Well this is embarrassing: the request was literally just timing out thanks to Australian upload speeds.